# Neovim: ¿Es posible abrir un archivo .html, .css, .js en el que se encuentre con un navegador sin salir del editor?

Tags: consola, vim

No he podido descifrar una forma y quisiera saber si conocen algún plugin o saben de algún atajo para lograr **abrir los archivos en los que se encuentran en *Neovim* con su navegador predeterminado** y **sin salir del archivo sería lo ideal** ¡Ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Las preguntas pidiendo opiniones, o del tipo ¿cómo hago tal o cual cosa? no son bien recibidas. Es posible que tu pregunta termine cerrada por no ajustarse a los requerimientos del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para abrir el archivo actual en chrome yo uso lo siguiente:
`:term open %`.

1. `:term` me permite usar comandos de la terminal.
2. `open` sirve para abrir archivos en la terminal.
3. `%` sirve para decirle que es el actual archivo.

Creo que también funciona con python, usando `:term python %`.

Answer (score 0):

Parecerá una tontería pero la solución que recién encontré para esto, por error, fue:

1. Salir del archivo en Neovim en el cual me encontraba.
2. Abrir un archivo index.html tipeando desde la consola:

```
index.html
```

3. Cambiar a la ventana de la consola y volver a abrir el archivo que estaba editando.

Con esto sigo aprendiendo y logré mi objetivo que es hacer todo con el teclado.

Espero que a alguien le sirva. ¡Saludos!